# Laravel Cors Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

Suddenly getting the following alarm

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://traxit-backend.test/api/register with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Failed to load http://traxit-backend.test/api/register: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

OPTIONS http://traxit-backend.test/api/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

It's been working fine with my configuration but just started acting up today. Im not sure if i need to do something. Tried different things I've read about on the internet with no luck

kernal.php file

```
protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
```

cors.php file

```
  'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

im using vuejs with axios on my front end. using laravel passport for access tokens.

Answer (score 0):

added  'allowedHeaders' => ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'],

Not sure what changed, but it fixed it

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,

];
```

Comment: That fix would indicate that some frontend JavaScript code is adding an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the request. So the real solution is to fix that frontend code to quit adding an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the request. Because Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header